# Which one sounds natural?

Tags: american-english

Which one of the following sentences sounds natural?

(1) Do you think I will have a chance to talk to her at the party?
(2) Do you think I could have a chance to talk to her at the party?

Answer (score 1):

(1) is hoping that it will occur
(2) is similar, with a colloquial implication that you are asking the speaker for permission to talk to her.